# Empty-handed or hands were empty

Tags: word-usage

> He was empty-handed.

Is it suitable if I change this sentence into

> His hands were empty.

In my point of view, the second sentence cannot describe "his unsuccessful task".Because "empty-handed" means "without getting what you hope".

Comment: You're correct, the second sentence isn't always a replacement for the first.  "Empty-handed" can be used either literally or idiomatically, and the rephrased sentence only covers the literal interpretations.

Comment: What about **bare-handed**?

Answer (score 1):

In some situations the example above is a suitable substitute. There is however, some nuance of meaning. So the answer is: it depends on the context and the meaning you want to convey.